# Simulate application shortcut on simulator

Tags: ios, ios9, 3dtouch

Can I simulate application shortcut on simulator? (With 3D Touch for ios 9)

What is force touch pressure for?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you all for your quick help. I find this one that can simulate application shortcut. I have tested and it is working.

https://github.com/DeskConnect/SBShortcutMenuSimulator

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible now unfortunately. force touch pressure is different from 3D touch. force touch pressure is for Apple Watch.

Answer (score 0):

As per apples documentation

> With Xcode 7.0 you must develop on a device that supports 3D Touch.
>   Simulator in Xcode 7.0 does not support 3D Touch.

In the simulator menu you seeing **Force Touch Pressure** is for Apple Watch simulator

You can refer this in the apple developer (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Adopting3DTouchOniPhone/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016543-CH1-SW7)